# fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am uploading a blob file in azure storage, it works on others browsers like google chrome/firefox/microsoft edge but when it comes to using safari browsers, I keep having an error of `fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory`

here is my javascript code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
    .then(function(mediaStreamObj) {
        //connect the media stream to the first video element
        let video = document.querySelector('video');
        if ("srcObject" in video) {
            video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
        } else {
            //old version
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObj);
        }
        //add listeners for saving video/audio
        let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
        let chunks = [];

        start.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            $("#vid_media_recorder").prop('muted', false);
            video.play();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        })
        stop.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        });
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
            chunks.push(ev.data);
        }
        mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev) => {
            let blob = new Blob(chunks, {
                'type': 'video/mp4;'
            });
            chunks = [];
            let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('blob', blob);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "media",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data: formData,
                processData: false, //add this
                contentType: false, //and this
                success: function(data) {
                    media_identifier = false;
                    $("#vid_media_recorder").prop('muted', true);
                    alert(data.path_azure);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.name, err.message);
    });
```

I'm just generating a blob file here which is a video using MediaRecorder once it is generated and the recording stop, it will just pass it through ajax using formdata.

here is my controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->file('blob')->storeAs(
            'test_capture', Str::random(16) .'.mp4', 'azure'
        );
        return response()->json([
            'success'=>"Success",
            'path_azure'=> $path
        ]);
    }
```

my controller is just simple once it received the blob file, it will just upload it on the azure storage.

the problem is when I am using safari, it keeps getting an error of `fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21` is there anyone who can help me with this?

the error also keeps me on pointing in my vendor file which is the

```
vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Stream.php line 228


    public function read($length)
    {
        if (!isset($this->stream)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Stream is detached');
        }
        if (!$this->readable) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot read from non-readable stream');
        }
        if ($length < 0) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Length parameter cannot be negative');
        }

        if (0 === $length) {
            return '';
        }

        $string = fread($this->stream, $length);
        if (false === $string) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to read from stream');
        }

        return $string;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, I already saw that, but I did not even use file_get_contents().

Comment: Safari version?

Comment: @GrafiCode version 15 sir.

Comment: the fact that the problem only occurs on Safari makes me think it's client-side related, like as if from Safari the blob is malformed / empty or something. What if you `print_r($request->file('blob'));`, is there any useful output?